# How to compare nested array with the map or filter and only return with first match inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Following are the code snippet for the data object which contains the information for the codeworks array representing the code and text.
I have one code key array like code = ["ABC","MDH"] and I want the expected out as represented into the code snippets.

```js
const data = {
    pData: {
      data: [
        {
          codeworks: [
            {
              code: "MDH",
              text: "Total Care MDH0"
            },
            {
              code: "MDH",
              text: "Total Care MDH1"
            },
            {
              code: "MDH",
              text: "Total Care MDH2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          codeworks: [
            {
              code: "ABC",
              text: "Total Care ABC"
            },
            {
              code: "MDH",
              text: "Total Care MDH"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          codeworks: [
            {
              code: "MDH",
              text: "text0"
            },
            {
              code: "XYZ",
              text: "text1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  
  code = ["ABC","MDH"]
  
  Expected Output : ['Total Care MDH0','Total Care ABC','text0']
```

I tried using the following ways,

```js
 const networkCodes = ["ABC", "MDH"];
 if (
      data &&
      data.pData&&
      data.pData.data &&
      data.pData.data.length > 0
    ) {
      const pDataItems = data.pData.data;
      let filteredItems = [];
      const acceptingNewItems =
        pDataItems &&
        pDataItems.length > 0 &&
        pDataItems.forEach((providerInfoObj, index) => {
          const networks =
            providerInfoObj &&
            providerInfoObj.codeworks&&
            providerInfoObj.codeworks.length > 0 &&
            providerInfoObj.codeworks; 

          /* eslint-disable-next-line */
          for (let j = 0; j < networks.length; j++) {
            const ele = networks[j]; 
            const findNetworkCodes =
            networkCodes && networkCodes.length > 0 && networkCodes;
            for (let index = 0; index < findNetworkCodes.length; index++) {
              const element = findNetworkCodes[index];
              if (element === ele.code) {
                filteredItems.push(ele.text);
              } 
              
            }
           
          }

          //return filteredItems ;
        });
      console.log(filteredItems );
    }
```

I did not get the output as expected into the snippets as denoted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long to understand. I think it could be expressed in short like below.

```
  const res = data.pData.data
    .map(({codeworks}) => {
      const matchedCodework = codeworks.find(codework => code.includes(codework.code));
      return matchedCodework ? matchedCodework.text : null;
    })
    .filter(text => text != null)

  console.log(res)
```